# Cannot use session from client after authentication using passport-local

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, express, passport.js

I'm trying to write a small user authentication module using express, passport-local, mongoose. User authentication works fine, but I am not able to use the authenticated user in further sessions.

Have gone through most of the suggestions on Stackoverflow, and other places, but none seems to work here.

The miniature version of my code is as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var session = require('express-session');

function genuuid(req) {
  return "UUID";
}

var app=express('');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

//user config
var userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({ username: String, password: String});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

var CreateUser = function(req, res) {
  var user = new User();
  user.username = req.body.username;
  user.password = req.body.password;
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (!err)
       res.json({message: "User created"});
    else
       res.send(err);
  });
}

//passport config
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, callback) {
    User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
      if (!user)
        callback(null, false);
      else
        callback(null, {id: user.id});
    });
  }
));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  return done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    return done(err, user);
  });
});

var Authenticate = passport.authenticate('local', {session: true});
var IsLoggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    next();
  else
    res.json({message: "Not logged In"});
}

app.use(session({
  genid: function(req) {
    return genuuid()
  },
  name: 'server-session-cookie-id',
  secret: 'carxpertsecret',
  cookie: {maxAge: 60000 },
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  //store: new FileStore()
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


var router = express.Router();

router.route('/secretdata').
  get(IsLoggedIn, function(req, res) { res.send("Secret Data")});


router.route('/createUser').
  post(CreateUser);

router.route('/login').
  post(Authenticate, function(req, res) { res.send("user authenticated")});

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

Now I create a user as below:

```
$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/createUser -X POST -d "username=foo&password=foo123"


* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /api/createUser HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 28
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 28 out of 28 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 26
< ETag: W/"1a-BL5+lbfL5b+1LNJK6XUFRA"
< Date: Mon, 04 Apr 2016 23:31:14 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
{"message":"User created"}
```

And then login(authenticate) using the newly created user:

```
$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/login -X POST -d "username=foo&password=foo123"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 28
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 28 out of 28 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 18
< ETag: W/"12-oAQqrjPB7C8RdFEBpTkRdQ"
< set-cookie: server-session-cookie-id=s%3AUUID.y6%2BRWOBpX%2Ffg6mVomXev1bhxB1LU0RarUvCYME9DR5I; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 04 Apr 2016 23:32:20 GMT; HttpOnly
< Date: Mon, 04 Apr 2016 23:31:20 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
user authenticated
```

I get the newly created session in form of cookie ( see set-cookie header above), and when I try to use this session in subsequent requests ( as below), the user is not authenticated using this session:

```
$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/secretdata --cookie 'server-session-cookie-id=s%3AUUID.y6%2BRWOBpX%2Ffg6mVomXev1bhxB1LU0RarUvCYME9DR5I'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /api/secretdata HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: server-session-cookie-id=s%3AUUID.y6%2BRWOBpX%2Ffg6mVomXev1bhxB1LU0RarUvCYME9DR5I
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 27
< ETag: W/"1b-hZjo3NVGururbXsBRiO5+Q"
< Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2016 00:07:18 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
{"message":"Not logged In"}
```

Please help me debug this issue.